# Open WPF Popup on TextBox focus

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to open a popup when the focus is on a text box
Here is the code I wrote :

```
<Window x:Class="Testpopup.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox  x:Name="text" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus" />
        <Button Click="Button_Click"  Content="but"/>
        <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="100" Height="100" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=text}"
            StaysOpen="False">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DatePicker />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void text_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

If I Click on the button everything works fine
If I Click on the text box the popup open and close

If I remove StaysOpen="False"  the popup open but never close

I try to set the focus on the popup before opening it but it does not work as well

Do you have any idea ?

Many thanks,
Nidal.

Comment: Have you tried with triggers? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following binding to your Popup-declaration:

```
StaysOpen="{Binding ElementName=text,Path=IsKeyboardFocused}"
```

This should do the trick.